# Blender 2.82 how to get linked edges

Tags: python

Im trying this `for edge in vertex.link_edges:` but gets

> 'MeshVertex' object has no attribute 'link_edges'

Thanks

Comment: Hello ! `link_edges` is a member of bpy.types.BMVert, not bpy.types.MeshVertex. ie you need to use a bmesh, not a regular mesh. https://docs.blender.org/api/2.82/bmesh.types.html?highlight=link_edges#bmesh.types.BMVert.link_edges Please add a bit of context to your code so we understand a bit better what your script does. Cheers

Comment: Im trying to analyze a mesh for local variation. Its a game terrain. I need to find open terrain and vice versa